# Which is correct ? to / in the same date

Tags: grammar

1. Joyce Carol Oates writes the best book of her career and Sue Grafton moves the release of her new mystery [**`to the same date`**].
2. Joyce Carol Oates writes the best book of her career and Sue Grafton moves the release of her new mystery [`in the same date`].

2nd question : "moves" in the sentence means "change" date ? Thanks

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not a good way to pose the question. It is not clear what meaning you desire.  To move something *on* a date refers to the date on which the move was made.  To move something *to* a date means it has been rescheduled to occur on that date.  *On* Monday, I moved the Wednesday meeting *to* Friday.  "in" is wrong in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is very jumbled, but as far as your question is concerned, (1) is correct.

The second example "in the same date" can never be correct, but you can use "on" for dates as in:

> Joyce Carol Oates writes the best book of her career and Sue Grafton moves the release of her new mystery **on the same date**.

However that has a different meaning, the "moving" happened on the date of the release of the first novel, the release of the second novel is now unstated.

Comment: Hi, I have 1 most question , "moves" in the sentence means "change" date ? Thanks.

Comment: @seemunTeh yes but you would probably say "changes the release date" vs "moves the release". With move, the destination implies that it is the date of the release that is being moved, with change, I think you need to be specific you are changing the date, not something else like the location. Although you could probably just swap "moves" for "changes" and get away with it.

Comment: Actually it's an American drama, younger's subtitles.... For move, I only know its meaning as running or move destination as you explained. But in the sentence, move + date.. so I'm guessing that change the date. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @seemunTeh the meaning "move" depends on context, but yes it can apply to dates, times, locations.